# Is there evidence for claims that specific actions are moral due to intrinsic, objective features of those actions?

Tags: logic, ethics, philosophy-of-science

The phrase *moral realism* will be used to cover the idea that actions can be right or wrong, permitted or forbidden, etc. due to qualities that are internal to the objective nature of those actions. This contrasts with moral *idealism*, which (here) adverts to ideal, AKA abstract but subjective, descriptions of actions ("approved by an ideal observer," say).

In my experience, emotions are claimed to be neither reasonable nor unreasonable. Neither logical nor illogical. If emotions constitute morality, what effect would their neutral status have? Would morality too be neither reasonable nor unreasonable, neither logical nor illogical? Without emotions, would morality exist? And how so? "Moral" subjectivists, relativists and nihilists don't seem to believe morality can exist without emotions. They believe morality is a matter of opinion and preference

For example: the feeling and belief of a conservative person preferring anti-abortion laws would be no different from the feeling and belief of a liberal person preferring liberalized abortion laws. The feeling and belief of a person disliking certain races would be no different from the feeling and belief of a person expanding equal opportunity for all races. I could go on. There is one thing these examples have in common: every moral statement is implied to be on par with other preferences. The action of someone disliking ice cream would not be better or worse than the action of someone liking ice cream. Why would that not be true for moral statements?

Under the subjective, relative or nihilist "moral" system, the disliking of certain races couldn't even be considered racist for racism is prejudice against people on the basis of their race and prejudice implies the feeling or preference against a race is immoral eventhough no feeling or preference would be intrinsically immoral

What then are the arguments against "moral" subjectivism, relativism and nihilism? What evidence is there for an intrinsic and reasonable morality that does not depend on human opinions and feelings?

Comment: So, are you ever going to accept answers to any of the questions you've ever posted? Or provide answers to any other questions? Maybe I read them wrong but the relevant lists under your profile seem to show zero accepted answers and zero offered answers. Just sayin'...

Comment: I understand that the SE format is a little weird when applied to philosophy; "History of Philosophy" is the subset that would tend to have the most "canonical" replies available and then the subject might as well go under the HistorySE, perhaps. Even so, there are plenty of users here (Conifold, Hypnosifl, Mauro, CriglCragl, armand, etc.) who provide good or even excellent replies to local posts so I will be at least borderline optimistic and say that it is possible for PhilosophySE to fit the network well enough.

Comment: There's even a loophole when it comes to "no personal theories as an OP": turn the theory into the background assumptions for whatever your further question should end up being, and there you go. Maybe respondents will get hung up on the assumptions, but that's more on them, or at least as much on them as on you, at that point?

Comment: Other than hedonists, who thinks that "emotions constitute morality"?

Comment: why do you limit an intrinsic morality to humans? Don't most animals (and perhaps plants) have an intrinsic morality for others of their own species - and some for other species as well??

Comment: @KristianBerry Do you see convincing answers to the questions that have been posted? Even to the current question? Your own response was more like a defense of subjectivism and less like a defense of moral realism for which evidence was requested. Please correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: This question is ill-posed, though. Asking for simultaneous arguments about separate topics, so that you can defer accepting answers because they supposedly fail to answer every question, isn't what is expected, here. There's a clarity/focus expectation for questions on this site.

Comment: Jumbling together subjectivism, relativism, and nihilism, and trying to put it all under a heading of moral realism, is unfaithful to the actual concepts at issue. Subjectivism and relativism are not absolutely non-realist positions, for example, neither is error-theoretic nihilism.

Comment: @KristianBerry "Moral" subjectivism, relativism and nihilism are the opposites of moral realism. Jumbling them up together when arguing against them and for moral realism makes sense to me

Comment: @KristianBerry I have never seen a single person other than the armchair "philosophers" here claim that "moral" subjectivism, relativism and nihilism are somehow realist positions. Care to back up your claim with sources?

Comment: @KristianBerry Please define realism and non-realism. If "moral" subjectivism, relativism, and nihilism were not non-realist positions, what could be considered non-realist?

Comment: Per the SEP article "Moral Realism," "Moral realists are those who think that... moral claims do purport to report facts and are true if they get the facts right. Moreover, they hold, at least some moral claims actually are true. That much is the common and more or less defining ground of moral realism (although **some** accounts of moral realism see it as involving additional commitments, say to the independence of the moral facts from human thought and practice, or to those facts being objective in some specified way)" [emphasis added].

Comment: I am being prompted to avoid extended discussion in comments so I will leave off by noting that sec. 3 of that article is about psychology, and mentions motivational internalism, for example. A moral theory requiring this internalism will have a strong subjectivistic side but is still a theory of moral realism. Moreover, it's not MY job to define terms that YOU are using to formulate your question. That's arguing in bad faith, is it not?

Comment: @KristianBerry I define moral realism as a moral position referring to objective features of the world. A realist morality would be mind-independent. Subjectivism would be in direct opposition to realism. You might be confusing realism with cognitivism? Cognitivism could encompass subjectivism and error theory, but in no way would realism encompass subjectivism and error theory. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: I'll edit your OP to reflect your demarcation of the problem as such, but that's the best I can do at this point.

Comment: @KristianBerry Thank you for the edit. I like it. I also like your new answer :)

Comment: @KristianBerry I accepted your answer by the way

Comment: Thank you! I admit, sometimes I'm more aggressive than I should be, and I prefer trying to interpret a person's position as strongly as I can think to instead. So at first I was miffed by what I thought you were saying, but then I tried to figure out a way to understand your question more directly, including on your stated terms. I'm glad I was able to see eye-to-eye with you, and I'm glad my answer resonated with you in turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that outward behaviors express inward attitudes, it is difficult to conceive of an action as right for some entirely internal, objectivistic reason, even in principle. Moreover, (next to) nothing that we know of is entirely objectivistic anyway (much less absolute), ranging from the foundations of mathematics (which perchance are something like semiotic formalism) or logic (esp. such as in intuitionistic forms), to physics (irrevocable uncertainty, and the relativity of spacetime itself) to biology (the partly social construction of species or gender taxonomies). So one wonders if the bar is being set higher than is rational, or if expecting moral theories to meet such a standard is in the end hypocritical, no less.

Purely on terminological grounds, a position like that of G. E. Moore, or W. D. Ross, would be strongly objectivistic/realistic. The critic or skeptic will interpret the faculty of moral perception, supposed by theorists such as those, to be a masque covering over those theorists' personal preferences, but at least in principle, "I have an intuition of an irreducible moral property attaching to action-type *X*," is no more irrealistic than, "I perceive an irreducible color property attaching to object-type *Y*." Granting that colors are the subjective manifestations of the objective relationship between electromagnetic wavelengths and our visual cortex (waiving complications involving the representation of colors in imaginal space), we might pair Moorean/Rossian intuitions with the prefrontal cortex in turn.

So far, moral intuitionism would satisfy the objectivity horn of the dilemma; the interiority horn, not so much, however. If a moral property is built into the very concept of an action-type, it would be perforce, yet trivially, internal to the type, but then we need either a "naturalistic" picture of the property, or we are presupposing what we wanted to "prove." And subsequently, the question would arise as to whether any *particular* action matched up with whichever relevant type, e.g. I could very well say, "Murder, by definition, is wrong," but then go on to ask whether any action ever performed actually counts as murder as such. (I could equivocate and say that there certainly have been hundreds of millions of murders committed throughout recorded human history, but absent the independent "proof" that the distinctly *moral* definition of murder has been satisfied by those killings, I would be begging the question, I think.)

Coming full circle, then, it is hard to see what "naturalistic" property could be internal to an action-type and yet "objectivistic" *and* morally salient. When I blink, there are "natural," "objective," "intrinsic" geometrical qualities to my blinking. Actually, any action that is a kind of moving about, inherits whatever such properties are "natural" to motion more broadly. But if we are trying to assimilate moral properties to such "natural" ones as mere geometrical features of motion, I confess that we are looking for something even more obtuse than the "purely conscientious act" that John Rawls objected to (following Bertrand Russell and Ludwig Wittgenstein, IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there evidence for an intrinsic and reasonable morality?

Intrinsic *to what*?

---

If to humans, there's plenty of evidence! Most people consider that murder, slavery, deception and pain are bad things, regardless of culture – and most people have would, given the option, *not* inflict bad things upon strangers. Most people value those close to them more than they value strangers. Most people consider it worthwhile to do bad things to strangers if it helps them do good things for those nearby.

But most people don't murder, torture or enslave strangers, even when it might benefit those around them! If you're wondering how that might arise, [Plato had something to say about that](http://classics.mit.edu/Plato/republic.3.ii.html).

> They say that to do injustice is, by nature, good; to suffer injustice, evil; but that the evil is greater than the good. And so when men have both done and suffered injustice and have had experience of both, not being able to avoid the one and obtain the other, they think that they had better agree among themselves to have neither.

Imagine two people. One is nice to you. The other killed your cousin. You have eaten you fill, and have some spare bread left over. Which person are you going to give it to?

People benefit from positive relations with each other. Helping others is good, and harming others is bad. If you've spent much time with a human, you'll know that humans aren't usually very good at nuance. Morality generalises this: helping others is good *even if it doesn't help you*, and harming others is bad *even if it doesn't help you*.

In other words: humans tend to be decent to each other. That's a good thing that makes things better for everybody, even though most of us could get much more money and status and power via the surgical application of violence and cruelty and lies.

Is this strictly rational? Well… what use is rationality, if it doesn't help guide you to do what you want to do? I see no reason to define "rationality" as something like "ruthlessly exploit everybody as effectively as possible".

Think of basic human decency as a tacit agreement that you never made. Rather, it's part of who you are – at least, probably. (If it's not, I hope you abide by it anyway. We're counting on you!)

> Would morality too be neither reasonable nor unreasonable, neither logical nor illogical? Without emotions, would morality exist? And how so?

*With* emotions, does morality exist? A plane crash makes you sad, but why is sadness bad? Why should you prefer happiness?

Once some states of the world are preferable and some are not preferable, utilitarianism falls out, and you can start [doing science to determine what is moral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_of_morality). Without that, though, you're stuck.

> There is no justice in the laws of Nature, no term for fairness in the equations of motion. The universe is neither evil, nor good, it simply does not care. The stars don't care, or the Sun, or the sky.
>
> Tell me, will *you* become a monster?
>
> — Eliezer Yudkowsky

---

Is morality intrinsic to the *universe*? Well, there's plenty of evidence for that: religious texts being a notable example. It's been [widely debated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_conflict) how valid this evidence is, but it *is* there.

Many religions have moral *rules*. No ending the life of another, no taking what is not yours, no other gods before God, no boiling a calf in its mother's milk. You have a duty to follow these rules.

Actions, not states of the world, are what is right or wrong.

Are these rules intrinsic? They were handed down by God, who created / is the universe; how could they *not* be? And are they reasonable? … Yeah, I can see reasons for all of these, and I can reason *about* them.

I won't elaborate on religious ethics further, because it varies *loads* by religion. ([Buddhist ethics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_ethics) isn't even particularly deontological.) There is [evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_epistemology) for *all* of these ethical systems being intrinsic to the fundamental nature of reality, even if [some evidence is weaker than other evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_spaghetti_monster#History).

---

> the feeling and belief of a conservative person preferring anti-abortion laws would be no different from the feeling and belief of a liberal person preferring liberalized abortion laws

This doesn't follow. Most people I've spoken to have a moral stance on this issue based on their beliefs about factual, empirical questions:

- Do people get souls at conception?
- Can embryos think and feel?
- Is it more dangerous for you to have an abortion or to give birth?
- Is abortion painful or distressing for a fœtus?

Only part of the disagreement is due to differences in their relative moral weighting of one person's bodily autonomy v.s. another person's life, or how much suffering a life is worth.

The feeling of "I am doing the right and moral thing by being an activist for this cause", though? That *would* probably be much the same for any moral crusader.

I'm not certain why this *matters*, though. It doesn't seem to follow from anything else in your question, and nothing else in your question follows from it.

> The action of someone disliking ice cream would not be better or worse than the action of someone liking ice cream. Why would that not be true for moral statements?

Because it is wrong to think wrong things are righteous.

I must confess I don't understand the question. If you have a concept of "better" or "worse", then you already have a standard by which you should judge moral statements. (Notice I said "should" there?)

> Under the subjective, relative or nihilist "moral" system, the disliking of certain races couldn't even be considered racist for racism is prejudice against people on the basis of their race and prejudice implies the feeling or preference against a race is immoral eventhough no feeling or preference would be intrinsically immoral

Wiktionary has [several definitions of prejudice](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prejudice), which boil down to something like “an adverse judgement, opinion, fear or hatred of – or hostility towards – a particular group or its members, formed beforehand without evidence”. Nothing about this definition requires or implies prejudice to be a *wrong* thing.

Your perception of that "implication" comes from *your morality*. The lack of intrinsic morality is not the same as the lack of morality.

> The stars don't care, or the Sun, or the sky. But they don't have to! *We* care! There *is* light in the world, and it is *us!*
>
> — Eliezer Yudkowsky

---

> What evidence is there for an intrinsic and reasonable morality that does not depend on human opinions and feelings?

A wealthy mansion-owner went on a three-day trip to the moon. An arsonist and a burglar both took the opportunity to target the unoccupied mansion. The burglar sabotaged the security system, the arsonist torched the place, and the police found them standing by the ruins, yelling obscenities at each other.

With all evidence either deleted or incinerated, the best the police can pin on them is common assault, with a maximum sentence of six months. Knowing this, they put the arsonist and the burglar in separate cells, then propose a deal to each of their prisoners: testify against the other in court, and you'll get a lighter sentence.

- If the arsonist testifies against the burglar, the police will drop the assault charge against the arsonist. However, the burglar will go to prison for ten years – the maximum possible prison sentence.
- If the burglar testifies against the arsonist, the burglar will walk free. However, the arsonist faces a similar ten-year sentence.
- If they both testify, they'll both be charged – but the judge will halve their sentences to five years, for co-operating with the law.

Regardless of what the other does, each prisoner has a choice between two options:

- Testifying means either freedom, or 5 years in prison.
- Remaining silent means either six months, or 10 years in prison.

What will the prisoners choose? Well, it depends what they care about – but if they're not depending on their emotions or feelings, then [decision theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_theory) is how they'll decide what they should do. There are several decision theories they might use; this is another place where I'm not an expert, so I'll link you to [somebody else's big list of decision theories](https://casparoesterheld.com/a-comprehensive-list-of-decision-theories/). Some highlights:

- [Causal decision theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_decision_theory) says that if they care about their freedom, the prisoners should betray each other to the police; the decision of the arsonist has no causal effect on the decision of the burglar, and vice versa, so they'll pick the action that gives the best outcome in expectation.
- [Evidential decision theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidential_decision_theory) says that if the prisoners expect that the other will use the same reasoning process – for instance, if they had a conversation about evidential decision theory and their mutual dislike of being in prison on the way to the police station – then the decision of the arsonist provides evidence about what the burglar would've decided (and vice versa). Knowing this, they'll both choose as though they're probably going to choose the same thing, both choosing to remain silent.

Answer (score 0):

Consider two definitions of “moral”:

Definition 1:  Assume the phrase “are moral” refers to actions that are what everyone, everywhere, somehow ought to do regardless of their needs and preferences. I know of no intrinsic, objective features of such actions.

Definition 2:  Assume the phrase “are moral’ refers to actions that are consistent with the principles that explain what we can call “human morality” (past and present cultural moral norms and our moral sense’s judgments and motivations). Then yes, there are intrinsic, objective features of such actions.

The following two principles appear to be consistent with the modern view of “human morality” (as defined above) as elements of strategies that solve cooperation problems. For an introduction to the science of morality, see Oliver Curry’s papers on Morality as Cooperation and Martin Nowak’s book “SuperCooperators”.

1. Culturally moral behaviors are elements of strategies that solve cooperation problems.
2. Universally moral behaviors are elements of strategies that solve cooperation problems and do not exploit others.

The cooperation problems that morality solves are as innate to our universe as the mathematics that define them in game theory. All species that form highly cooperative species must have solved them. All highly cooperative species can be expected to have biological or culturally dependent behaviors that fulfill the necessary function of “human morality” as defined above.

So the intrinsic, objective features of actions that are universally moral are that 1) they are elements of strategies that solve cooperation problems and 2) do not exploit others.

For example, “Do to others as you would have them to do you” is a heuristic (a usually reliable but fallible rule of thumb) for initiating indirect reciprocity, perhaps the most powerful cooperation strategy known. We can identify the strategy it initiates as “universally moral” since it advocates behaviors that solve cooperation problems without exploiting others.

Keeping in mind that the Golden Rule is only a fallible heuristic, there are well-known cases, such as when dealing with criminals, in times of war, and when “tastes differ”, when it can fail.

However, even if the Golden Rule is a heuristic, we can expect that a version of it will likely be present in the cultural moral norms of all intelligent, highly cooperative species simply due to the power of the cooperation strategy that it initiates. So even though fallible, we can still expect the Golden Rule to be universally moral.